# Does the "Fresh Air in the Tunnels" buff need to be used immediately?

Tags: darkest-dungeon

I did a quest and got the event "Fresh Air in the Tunnels", which provides extra Damage and Resolve in the Warrens on the next quest.

Do I need to do a quest in The Warrens this week to use the buff? If I go to the courtyard to get The Blood instead, will the buff have gone by next week?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

"Fresh Air in the Tunnels" is Town Event, which occurs only for one week. If you do any other quest, week will pass, along with event. So yes, if you want to make some use of this Town Event, you should do quest in Warrens.